# is there a faster way to get multiple keys from dictionary?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, key-value

I have a dictionary:

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
```

Then I have a list of keys:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'z']
```

My desired result is:

```
[1, 2, None]
```

What I'm doing so far is:

```
[d.get(k) for k in l]
```

Is there a faster way? Perhaps without `for`?

Comment: `list(map(d.get, l))` might be marginally faster. But at this level of micro-optimization I suggest if it matters move onto C or other lower-level language.

Comment: `[d.get(k) for k in l]` is a perfectly cromulent way to do it. What exactly are you unhappy about? Performance? Readability? Brevity?

Comment: It's a shame `operator.itemgetter` always raises a `KeyError` instead of allowing for a default value for an undefined key; otherwise you could use `itemgetter(*l)(d)`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use:

```
>>> list(map(d.get, l))
[1, 2, None]
```

It has two advantages:

- It performs the `d.get` lookup only once - not each iteration
- Only CPython: Because `dict.get` is implemented in C and `map` is implemented in C it can avoid the Python layer in the function call (roughly speaking the details are a bit more complicated).

As for timings (performed on Python 3.6 in a Jupyter notebook):

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
l = ['a', 'b', 'z']

%timeit list(map(d.get, l))
594 ns ± 41.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit [d.get(k) for k in l]
508 ns ± 17.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Note that this is actually slower in this case! That's because for short iterables the `map` and `list` overhead dominate. So if you want it faster on short iterables stick with your approach.

With longer `l` you see that `list(map(...))` eventually becomes faster:

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
l = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(10000)]

%timeit list(map(d.get, l))
663 µs ± 64.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit [d.get(k) for k in l]
1.13 ms ± 7.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

However that's still "just" a factor of 2 faster.

Answer (score 6):

It is important to note that the bottle neck here is not the size of the dictionary, but the size of the list of keys (and of course method look-up time, time it takes to hash the key being looked up, etc.)

Consider the following:

```
from timeit import Timer

d = {1: 'a'}
keys = [1 for _ in range(1000)]

def _map():
    return list(map(d.get, keys))

def _map_single_lookup():
    g = d.get
    return list(map(g, keys))

def _list_comp():
    return [d.get(key) for key in keys]

def _list_comp_single_lookup():
    g = d.get
    return [g(key) for key in keys]

print(min(Timer(_map).repeat(100, 100)))
print(min(Timer(_map_single_lookup).repeat(100, 100)))
print(min(Timer(_list_comp).repeat(100, 100)))
print(min(Timer(_list_comp_single_lookup).repeat(100, 100)))

#  0.009307396466818774
#  0.009261678214412816
#  0.018456645101335933
#  0.011634828724497837
```

Comment: Your `_map` and `_map_single_lookup` are exactly equivalent. They both require only a single lookup of `d.get`.

Comment: @jmd_dk I'm not 100% sure to be honest. `_map_single_lookup` is consistently faster

Comment: But not because of the `d.get` lookup time. As the `list*` tests demonstrate, that difference should be much larger.

Comment: If true, that is interesting. But it is syntactically impossible for the two to lookup `d.get` a different number of times, as the only iterative behavior happens inside of functions (here the `map`). That is, each sub-expression is evaluated once, as opposed to the list comprehension.

Comment: @jmd_dk I agree. Must be just a fluke then.

Comment: It's possible that you're triggering some compiler optimisation by assigning to a variable; but I have no idea what in detail that would be.

Answer (score 3):

A much faster alternative would be to use `itemgetter` with `defaultdict` (because `itemgetter` doesn't support a default value like `dict.get` in case the key doesn't exist)

```
from collections import defaultdict
from timeit import Timer
from operator import itemgetter

d = defaultdict(lambda: None)
d[1] = 'a'
keys = [1 for _ in range(1000)]

def _map():
    return list(map(d.get, keys))

def _getter():
    return list(itemgetter(*keys)(d))

print(min(Timer(_map).repeat(100, 100)))
print(min(Timer(_getter).repeat(100, 100)))

# 0.0074976040767260055
# 0.0021861597102568187
```

**Edit** Added timings for non-existing keys (integers and strings). No significant impact on the performance.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from timeit import Timer
from operator import itemgetter

d = defaultdict(lambda: None)
d[1] = 'a'
non_existing_keys_int = [2 for _ in range(1000)]
non_existing_keys_string = ['a' for _ in range(1000)]

def get_non_existing_keys_int():
    return list(itemgetter(*non_existing_keys_int)(d))

def get_non_existing_keys_string():
    return list(itemgetter(*non_existing_keys_string)(d))

print(min(Timer(get_non_existing_keys_int).repeat(100, 100)))
print(min(Timer(get_non_existing_keys_string).repeat(100, 100)))

#  0.002647169132724954
#  0.002408539023506795
```

Comment: Do you have any timings that include non-existing keys and not-integers? These might have a significant effect on the performance.

Comment: @MSeifert I updated the answer. Non-existing keys don't have a significant impact on the performance

Answer (score 1):

[getpy](https://github.com/atom-moyer/getpy) is a library that allows fast parallel hashmap operations based on a C++ lib by what better name than [parallel-hashmap](https://github.com/greg7mdp/parallel-hashmap)? Here's an ipython session that shows getting 1000 values is over 200x faster using parallel read!

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: import getpy as gp

In [2]: key_type = np.dtype('u8')
   ...: value_type = np.dtype('u8')

In [3]: keys = np.random.randint(1, 1000, size=10**2, dtype=key_type)
   ...: values = np.random.randint(1, 1000, size=10**2, dtype=value_type)
   ...: 
   ...: gp_dict = gp.Dict(key_type, value_type, default_value=42)
   ...: gp_dict[keys] = values
   ...: 
   ...: random_keys = np.random.randint(1, 1000, size=500, dtype=key_type)

In [4]: %timeit random_values = gp_dict[random_keys]
2.19 µs ± 11.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit [gp_dict[k] for k in random_keys]
491 µs ± 3.51 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```